# MVC Get ID of object

Tags: asp.net-mvc

in the following post: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html

```
<%= Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName) %>
```

Html.Editor creates a text box with MVC generated name. How do I get/access that name? id?

So in my code this gets generated:

```
<input type="text" value="Right" name="Template.RightColumn.ContainerName" id="Template_RightColumn_ContainerName">
```

and I want to generate this:

```
<div id="Template_RightColumn_ContainerName"></div>
```

so I need to access PropertyId. how do i do it?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it. you can use these:

```
<%: ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix %>
```

or

```
<%: ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("HtmlContent") %>
```

where HtmlContent is the name of your field. prefix will be generated automatically.
thanks